# expanding data columns by row value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data which looks like:

```
      Nivell   Codi                         Nom
1    Comarca      1                    Alt Camp
2   Municipi 430017                 Aiguamúrcia
3   Municipi 430056                     Alcover
4   Municipi 430108                        Alió

...

25   Comarca      2                 Alt Empordà
26  Municipi 170010                    Agullana
27  Municipi 170031                     Albanyà
28  Municipi 170059           Far d'Empordà, el
29  Municipi 170118               Armentera, l'
```

I would like to create a new column in the data for `comarca`. So each `municipi` under its given `comarca` will have the corresponding `comarca` value.

Expected output:

```
      Nivell   Codi                         Nom    comarca      comarcaNo
2   Municipi 430017                 Aiguamúrcia    Alt Camp         1
3   Municipi 430056                     Alcover    Alt Camp         1
4   Municipi 430108                        Alió    Alt Camp         1

...

26  Municipi 170010                    Agullana    Alt Empordà      2
27  Municipi 170031                     Albanyà    Alt Empordà      2
28  Municipi 170059           Far d'Empordà, el    Alt Empordà      2
29  Municipi 170118               Armentera, l'    Alt Empordà      2
```

SO now the `comarca` has been removed and expanded into the two additional columns.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Nivell = c("Comarca", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Comarca", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Comarca", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", "Municipi", 
"Municipi"), Codi = c(1L, 430017L, 430056L, 430108L, 430347L, 
430363L, 430593L, 430666L, 430803L, 430831L, 430897L, 430918L, 
430982L, 431080L, 431135L, 431191L, 431205L, 431248L, 431325L, 
431346L, 431606L, 431613L, 431652L, 431704L, 2L, 170010L, 170031L, 
170059L, 170118L, 170123L, 170144L, 170160L, 170268L, 170293L, 
170307L, 170314L, 170329L, 170412L, 170427L, 170470L, 170519L, 
170524L, 170545L, 170600L, 170622L, 170643L, 170669L, 170741L, 
170754L, 170773L, 170865L, 170887L, 170926L, 170932L, 171002L, 
171024L, 171061L, 171117L, 171156L, 171194L, 171208L, 171289L, 
171292L, 171328L, 171352L, 171365L, 171387L, 171404L, 171432L, 
171518L, 171523L, 171582L, 171714L, 171753L, 171766L, 171788L, 
171827L, 171870L, 171886L, 171962L, 171984L, 172109L, 172142L, 
172174L, 172214L, 172229L, 172235L, 172253L, 172266L, 172272L, 
172288L, 172305L, 172348L, 3L, 80137L, 80272L, 80581L, 80654L, 
80850L, 80919L), Nom = c("Alt Camp", "Aiguamúrcia", "Alcover", 
"Alió", "Bràfim", "Cabra del Camp", "Figuerola del Camp", "Garidells, els", 
"Masó, la", "Milà, el", "Montferri", "Mont-ral", "Nulles", 
"Pla de Santa Maria, el", "Pont d'Armentera, el", "Puigpelat", 
"Querol", "Riba, la", "Rodonyà", "Rourell, el", "Vallmoll", 
"Valls", "Vilabella", "Vila-rodona", "Alt Empordà", "Agullana", 
"Albanyà", "Far d'Empordà, el", "Armentera, l'", "Avinyonet de Puigventós", 
"Vajol, la", "Bàscara", "Borrassà", "Boadella i les Escaules", 
"Cabanes", "Cabanelles", "Cadaqués", "Cantallops", "Capmany", 
"Castelló d'Empúries", "Cistella", "Siurana", "Colera", "Darnius", 
"Escala, l'", "Espolla", "Figueres", "Fortià", "Garrigàs", 
"Garriguella", "Jonquera, la", "Lladó", "Llançà", "Llers", 
"Masarac", "Maçanet de Cabrenys", "Mollet de Peralada", "Navata", 
"Ordis", "Palau de Santa Eulàlia", "Palau-saverdera", "Pau", 
"Pedret i Marzà", "Peralada", "Pont de Molins", "Pontós", "Portbou", 
"Port de la Selva, el", "Rabós", "Riumors", "Roses", "Sant Climent Sescebes", 
"Sant Llorenç de la Muga", "Sant Miquel de Fluvià", "Sant Mori", 
"Sant Pere Pescador", "Santa Llogaia d'Àlguema", "Saus, Camallera i Llampaies", 
"Selva de Mar, la", "Terrades", "Torroella de Fluvià", "Ventalló", 
"Vilabertran", "Viladamat", "Vilafant", "Vilaür", "Vilajuïga", 
"Vilamacolum", "Vilamalla", "Vilamaniscle", "Vilanant", "Vila-sacra", 
"Biure", "Alt Penedès", "Avinyonet del Penedès", "Cabanyes, les", 
"Castellet i la Gornal", "Castellví de la Marca", "Font-rubí", 
"Gelida")), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `replace` and `fill` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(comarca = replace(Nom, Nivell != 'Comarca', NA), 
         comarcaNo = replace(Codi, Nivell != 'Comarca', NA)) %>%
  fill(comarca, comarcaNo) %>%
  filter(Nivell != 'Comarca')

#     Nivell   Codi                         Nom     comarca comarcaNo
#1  Municipi 430017                 Aiguamúrcia    Alt Camp         1
#2  Municipi 430056                     Alcover    Alt Camp         1
#3  Municipi 430108                        Alió    Alt Camp         1
#4  Municipi 430347                      Bràfim    Alt Camp         1
#5  Municipi 430363              Cabra del Camp    Alt Camp         1
#6  Municipi 430593          Figuerola del Camp    Alt Camp         1
#7  Municipi 430666              Garidells, els    Alt Camp         1
#8  Municipi 430803                    Masó, la    Alt Camp         1
#9  Municipi 430831                    Milà, el    Alt Camp         1
#10 Municipi 430897                   Montferri    Alt Camp         1
#...
#...
```